# How can I get the Ubuntu Installer to recognize that my system has windows 10 installed?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm currently trying to dual boot my Dell inspiron 7000 series laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Windows 10 is already installed. However while messing with installing other linux distros i seem to have messed up where windows boots from (or something like that).

See, when I want to boot directly to Windows 10 i have to set BIOS to automatically boot from the Hard Disk which is labeled as (legacy boot options) (also when i boot from usb it shows up under legacy boot options). Theres also another label (UEFI boot options) which has Windows Boot Manager as its only option.

Now, when i run ubuntu from the usb drive and elect to install it, When i have an option of erasing everything or dual boot, or "something else", it doesnt recognize that I have windows Installed on the computer. So I am forced to choose "something else" where you select which partitions to install it to, but the only partitions are the windows partition and the windows recovery partition. It wont let me resize them, only erase one for the other.

Basically my problem is I need to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10, but somewhere in my boot options, I think I have messed something up. My question isnt necessarily how to dual boot ubuntu or set up the partitions cause I have done this before, but rather what can I change so that the ubuntu installer recognizes that my system has windows 10 installed.

Comment: would it help if i posted a pic of my Boot settings?

Comment: Yes ! Please post the pictures of your BIOS settings.

Comment: You must have Windows fast start up off which is always on hibernation. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 8 screens which are like Windows 10 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Windows in Legacy Mode of your BIOS , then install Ubuntu also in Legacy mode by selecting the USB option under Legacy boot options or if you have installed Windows in UEFI mode of your BIOS then you have to install Ubuntu also in UEFI mode by selecting USB option under UEFI boot options.

After booting into any one of the BIOS Boot modes you should see that Ubuntu recognizes you already installed Windows partition and its corresponding version.

After that select the **"Something Else"** option and proceed your installation.